# Creating a custom header

Tags: css, custom-header

I am using the greyzed theme and want to create a custom header using my own image. my computer skills are limited and i have no idea where to start or how to even open the php files if that's what I need to do. I cant find any help online. Here is the image if it will work, "http://chefdude20.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/14/wolf-engines-logo/"

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Greyzed](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/greyzed) homepage you'll see that it is a theme which is no longer under active development. I wouldn't recommend this as you might not be able to get the most out of your WordPress site if your theme is out of date.

That being said, if you don't have the option to add a header image in the [Appearance](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Header_Screen) tab in your Admin section, then you would probably create a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for Greyzed and  use a functions.php file or edit the themes header.php. This can be complicated for a first timer, so it might be a good idea to grab a theme with custom header image support.